# Filtering a matrix by unique column elements

Tags: matlab, filter

M is a matrix: M = [X Y Z] where X, Y and Z are column vectors.

What is the easiest way to filter M so that:
1- No element is repeated per column
2- The order of the rows remain (if an element appears twice in a column, then I want to delete the entire row where it appears the second time)

e.g:

```
M = [1 2 4; 
1 3 5;
2 3 9]
```

would become

```
Mf = [1 2 4;
2 3 9]
```

I tried to use [u,~,ind] = unique(M,'rows') to have the elements for which one element in a column is repeated, but this function deals with the entire row (if only one element of the row is repeated, then the row is unique)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution, should be fine as long as you M isn't too big. I've tested it on a few matrices and it seems to work as intended.

```
count=1;
for i=1:length(M(1,:))^2
    [~,IA,~]=unique(M(:,count),'first');
    if length(IA)~=length(M(:,1))
        M=M(IA,:);
        count=count-1;
    end
    count=count+1;
    if count>length(M(:,1))
        break
    end
end
M
```

Comment: +1. But just out of curiosity as the anwser is already accepted. For `M = [1 2 4; 1 3 5;2 3 4]` it gives `M = [1 2 4; 2 3 4]`. 4 is repeated at the end. Is that correct?

Comment: @Marcin yes you are correct there is a serious problem with my code! I think I have fixed it now, but it is not very nice. I am sure there is a better way of doing this.